# CSV files uploading via ruby script as empty to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have a ruby script that creates a csv, then I take the created csv and upload it to Amazon S3 via another ruby script.

After running the `create_csv.rb` script, I get a valid csv and `cat file.csv` outputs the contents of the desired csv.

Then, I run another ruby script called `upload_csv_to_s3.rb` which looks like this:

```
$file = 'file.csv'
AWS.config(access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secret_access_key: $SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region: 'us-west-2')
bucket_name = $BUCKET
file_name = $file
# Get an instance of the S3 interface.
s3 = AWS::S3.new
# Upload a file.
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => file_name)
puts "Uploading file #{file_name} to bucket #{bucket_name}."
```

When running this script, I do get a warning logged to my console:

```
upload_csv_to_s3.rb:26: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/jcorser in PATH, mode 040777
```

This is because I have my permissions set to be dangerously open, which might be a part of the problem, but I am hoping not? (please don't give me advice on the security of my machine, I recognize this is a horrible idea and I wouldn't be mentioning it unless I thought this might be a cause for the specific failure I'm asking about in this question)

The file `file.csv` does seem to upload to S3, however, the contents of the file is completely blank, and does not contain the csv information that `file.csv` on my local machine contains.

Any ideas?

Comment: Weirdly, it works fine if I don't use the file name "file.csv'. Changing the name to file1.csv is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, it works fine if I don't use the file name `file.csv`. Changing the name to `file1.csv` is successful